# Retrieve Specific Tags in SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, hashtags

I'm having some trouble with the following, i'm sure it's possible but i don't seem to be able to find an answer online.

I'm looking at using the SharePoint 2013 REST API to try and pull back specific hashtags that the client asks for.

I've located the following resource but unable to find what i want on here or anywhere else on the interwebs.

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/social-feed-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint

Thanks for any help.
Ian.